# How to choose right transistor?

Tags: transistors, fet

I have been trying to design a differential amplifier for EEG.

How can I choose the right bipolar transistors and FETs according to my aims ?

Any guide will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Determine requirements (specifications, ie. actual numbers). Attempt to meet specifications with a design. Iterate, adjusting design or specifications until all requirements are satisfied.

Comment: Figure out what paramaters are important to you then visit a general vendor and use their parametric search tools.

Comment: You sure you want to build your own differential amplifier from components? For an EEG I would have started looking for a very good, high end IC.

Comment: Pretty advanced stuff. I would recommend you using an integrated analog front-end that is specially made for measuring biopotentials like the ADS1198 - it is basically a single-chip body-to-digital converter.

Comment: Until you understand how commercial designs work, with specs for noise level/bandwidth offset, SNR, your desire to design is in vein.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Intentional pun? (vein?)

Comment: I knew I could count on you to get it SP.

Comment: Or as the Brits would say  with a few dozen scalp electrodes, it would be a bloody mess.

Comment: For EEG, assuming 100 microVolts RMS signal  and 40dB SNR (100:1 ratio of signal-to-noise) and 100Hz bandwidth, your noise budget is (100uVrms/100) / sqrt(bandwidth) =   1uVrms / sqrt(100Hz) = 1uVrms/10 = 0.1 uVrms = 100 nanoVolts rms per root Hertz. Given 1Kohm produces 4 nanoVolts rms/rootHz, you have a margin of (100nV/4nV)^2 = 25^2 * 1kohm or 625,000 Ohms for your Rnoise. Picking opamps with 625,000 Rnoise *or* lower is easy; just examine the 1/F corner and pay a bit more for 100Hz or 10Hz 1/F corner ICs. Similar for the bipolars or FETs, if you choose the discrete approach. And have fun.

Comment: Bleeding edge technology?

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Is there any FET model that becomes on when ultra low input signal is applied ?

Answer (score 2):

To chose any part:

Look at the circuit carefully and list the required parameters.

Look around for a part that meets the parameters.  If you already have a good idea what product line has such a part or that you prefer to get a new part from, look around in that manufacturer's data.  Otherwise, look around on a distributor site that has good parametric search capability.

This really should have been obvious, but is about all that can be said to answer such a broad question.

Comment: This answer is not useful, either to the OP or future visitors, if you wondered why you got a downvote.

Comment: @Peter: It does, however, directly answer the question.  Note that I also voted to close this whole mess, and am surprised this answer got any votes before closure.  The point was to demonstrate to the OP how bad the question is.  Three others apparently thought the point was worth making.